# Xna/Monogame text disappear from one end and reappear on the other end

Tags: c#, text, xna, monogame

I am trying to figure out how to have text that cross the screen and when it arrives at one end it smoothly disappear little by little and reappear at the other end as it is disappearing.

I already have my text moving and my collision detection but I can't figure out how to do a smooth transition from one side to the other.

Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to draw two different strings containing the same text, one starting at `x = 0`, the other one should start from `x = -Window.ClientBounds.Width`.
In this way you simply need to increase both the `x` positions in your `Update`, so when the first string starts to disappear out of the right side of the screen the ending of the second string will appear from the left side of your screen.
Of course you need to change the `x` position of the string that's moving out of the screen everytime its position exceeds `Window.ClientBounds.Width`.

```
if (stringPosition1.x >= Window.ClientBounds.Width)
  stringPosition1.x -= 2 * Window.ClientBounds.Width;
```

If it's what you want.

Comment: I think it's the easiest and right way to do it. Another solution is to measure the length of the string char by char, and when the length exceed the right side of the screen you draw the remaining chars on the other side of the screen. But is a stupid solution IMHO.

Comment: @Mostaguen Clever is often not better. Simple solutions are easier to maintain, debug and take a lot less time to develop.